# Warning in the field

Tags: php, html

I have an error in a field after submit. Error is *Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in **/path/** on line 420*. Here is a snippet of code (420 line)

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="width: 100px; height:200px">
                <div style="position:absolute; top:0; margin:25px">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="exhibition" name="exhibition" value="Speaker">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="width:400px; height:50px"><b>Speaker</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:130px; height:50px">Section:</td>
            <td style="width:270px; height:50px"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fields[]" name="fields[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields']); ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:130px; height:50px">Topic report:</td>
            <td style="width:270px; height:50px"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fields[]" name="fields[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields']); ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:130px; height:50px">Required hardware:</td>
            <td style="width:270px; height:50px"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fields[]" name="fields[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields']); ?>"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

This snipped code is related with this php code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $institution = $_POST['institution'];
    $post = $_POST['post'];
    $degree = $_POST['degree'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $mailing = $_POST['mailing'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $site = $_POST['site'];
    $from = 'Energy-knutd'; 
    $from .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n" ."Content-type: text/plain; charset='utf-8'". "\r\n";
    $to = 'email@energy-knutd.netau.net'; 
    $subject = 'Member';    
    $form = implode(", ", (array)$_POST['participation']);
    $fields = implode(", ", (array)$_POST['fields']);
    $exhibition = $_POST['exhibition'];


    if($_POST['exhibition'])
    {
        $body ="From: $surname\n Surname: $name\n Institution: $institution\n Post: $post\n Degree: $degree\n Title: $title\n Mailing: $mailing\n Phone: $phone\n Email: $email\n Site: $site\n Form: $exhibition. $fields";
    } else {
        $body ="From: $surname\n Surname: $name\n Institution: $institution\n Post: $post\n Degree: $degree\n Title: $title\n Mailing: $mailing\n Phone: $phone\n Email: $email\n Site: $site\n Form: $form";
    }



    // Check if name has been entered
    if(!$_POST['surname']){
        $errSurname = 'Pleaes enter your surname';
    }

    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    if (!$_POST['institution']) {
        $errInstitution = 'Please enter your name of institution';
    }

    if (!$_POST['post']) {
        $errPost = 'Please enter your post';
    }

    if (!$_POST['mailing']) {
        $errMailing = 'Please enter your mailing address';
    }

    if (!$_POST['phone']) {
        $errPhone = 'Please enter your phone';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    if (!$_POST['confirm']) {
        $errConfirm = 'You should confirm with this statement';
    }

// If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errSurname && !$errInstitution && !$errPost && !$errMailing && !$errPhone && !$errConfirm) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result="<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank You $name! I will be in touch</div>";
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you want to echo out the specific field in the post array, it says in the error that the function only takes a string

Comment: It looks like it's an array and not a string. Did you mean to call hhtmlspecialchars($fields) instead of the $_POST('fields')?

Comment: "fields" is an array.  In multiple places in your code you explicitly define it and use it as an array.  The error is simply telling you that the function you're calling can't be called on an array.  What are you even *trying* to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars` wants a string, but you're giving it an array:

`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields']); ?>`

To access one of the values in your array, you just need to do something like this:

`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields']['your_sub_field']); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

When you give the form element a name ending with square brackets `fields[]` you are setting that value as an array,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fields[]" name="fields[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields']); ?>">
```

Then you are passing `$_POST['fields']` to `htmlspecialchars()` which as your error stated requires a string.

You need to change `htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields']);` to something like:

Implode all elements into a comma seperated list `ele1, ele2, ele3`

`htmlspecialchars(implode(", ", $_POST['fields']));`

or just the first element
`htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields'][0]);`

or a named `htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields']['myelement']);`

You need to somehow process your fields array and convert it to a string you would like to store/pass to the script.

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars() is expecting a string to be passed but you are passing an  array as a parameter. Also you are sending every field as an array, that's why $_POST['fields'] is an array which contains every field whose attribute name is equal to 'fields[]'. I'm not sure if that piece of HTML code is displayed after send the email or before, but I guess your trying to display the value sent by post.

If $_POST['fields'] is a numeric array and the section value is on the first position of the array, then you have to do something like this:

```
<td style="width:270px; height:50px"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fields[]" name="fields[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields'][0]); ?>"></td>
```

Anyway, in this case I don't understand why are you sending the values of these fields as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
<tr>
            <td style="width:130px; height:50px">Section:</td>
            <td style="width:270px; height:50px"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fields0" name="fields[0]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields'][0]); ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:130px; height:50px">Topic report:</td>
            <td style="width:270px; height:50px"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fields1" name="fields[1]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields'][1]); ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:130px; height:50px">Required hardware:</td>
            <td style="width:270px; height:50px"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fields2" name="fields[2]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fields'][2]); ?>"></td>
        </tr>
```

You should escape the mail input and the result input also.

Also id for html entities are supposed to be unique. If you want to identify multiple entities you should use a class.